# Need an automatism to insert in a table the missing rows of a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I don't have much experience with database so i am asking for help here in this situation:

THis select statement here is retrieving all the documents that are not in a table that i use to map my documents that are going to be integrated in other systems, it's a mapping table (TP_DOC_MAP). So i want to create some kind of automatism in my database that X in X time it will run this statement and it will insert in my mappings table (TP_DOC_MAP).

Right now it has been made manually. I run this statement and i will insert each record manually, and it doesn't make sense of course.

```
    (
    SELECT DOM_DOCUMENT.DOMAIN_DOC,
            TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOC_PK,
            TYPE_DOCS.TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
            TYPE_DOCS.USERCODE,
            TYPE_DOCS.CODE_RESULT
         FROM TYPE_DOCS 
        JOIN DOM_TDOC_SIS 
               ON TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOC_PK = DOM_TDOC_SIS.TYPE_DOC_PK
         JOIN DOM_DOCUMENT 
              ON DOM_TDOC_SIS.DOMAIN_DOC_PK = DOM_DOCUMENT.DOMAIN_DOC_PK
         WHERE DOM_DOCUMENT.DOMAIN_DOC_PK IN (2, 10) -- (QLD = | PRD = 2) 
     "motive docs" -- (QLD = 63 | PRD = 10) "Consent. docs"
    AND NOT EXISTS
                 (
                  SELECT 1
                    FROM TP_DOC_MAP
                   WHERE  TP_DOC_MAP.LS_LOCAL_PK = 8 
                         AND TP_DOC_MAP.LS_SYSTEM_PK = 3 -- system type
                         AND TP_DOC_MAP.ACTIVE = 1 -- Mapping all the active 
  documents
                         AND TP_DOC_MAP.CODE = TYPE_DOCS.TYPE_DOC_PK --"not e 
 xists" junction
                ))


    INSERT INTO TP_DOC(CODIGO, NAME, ACTIVE, CREATEDAT, UPDATEDAT) VALUES 
    ('TPDOC_23', 'Report for intrusive function', 1, SYSDATE, NULL);

    INSERT INTO TP_DOC_MAP (TP_DOCUMENT_PK, LS_LOCAL_PK, LS_SYSTEM_PK, CODE, 
    ACTIVE, CREATEDAT, UPDATEDAT) VALUES ((SELECT TP_DOCUMENT_PK FROM TP_DOC 
    WHERE CODE = 'TPDOC_23'), (SELECT LS_LOCAL_PK FROM LS_LOCAL WHERE CODE = 
   'IPE'), (SELECT LS_SYSTEM_PK FROM LS_SYSTEM WHERE CODIGO = 'MDS'), '21', 
    1, SYSDATE, NULL);
```

so i want t create a database routine to do this automatically.

Comment: [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) statement is what you are looking for.

Comment: i am thinking about creating a timer in Oracle to achieve this but in this case how do make this dynamic :  TP_DOC_MAP.LS_LOCAL_PK = 8 in this case is 8, but there are more i am mapping documents that are restricted to certain  LS_LOCAL_PK, how can i set this dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Convert that code into a procedure, e.g.

```
create or replace procedure p_insert as
begin
  insert into target_table (col1, col2, ...)
    select rows_that_are_missing
    from some_other_table
    where ...;
end;
```

Then schedule it using either `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` packages. For example:

```
declare
  l_job number;
begin
  dbms_job.submit
   (job       => job_insert, 
    what      => 'p_insert;'
    next_date =>  sysdate,
    interval  => 'sysdate + 1');
end;
```

Comment: thanks it helps about the structure! but tell me in that select statement i running the query for  TP_DOC_MAP.LS_LOCAL_PK = 8 as an example but there are 10 more TP_DOC_MAP.LS_LOCAL_PK, do i have to create a procedure for each and a scheduler for each PK?

Comment: I guess not; if possible, create a **loop** which will do inserting for each PK value.